# SELECT QUERY LIKE containing only specific words in a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table like below ,table name is **js_skills_achievements**

```
id   skill1  skill2  skill3  skill4
1     java    php    html    android
2     php     java   jquery  html
3     sql     php    html    jquery
```

When admin search key is "java developer in nersupalli"

my query is below

```
SELECT *
FROM `js_skills_achievements`
WHERE `skill1`  LIKE '%java developer in nersupalli%'
   OR `skill2`  LIKE '%java developer in nersupalli%'
   OR `skill3`  LIKE '%java developer in nersupalli%'
   OR `skill4`  LIKE '%java developer in nersupalli%'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Its not working for me . My Requirement is i need to display all java records . here total 2 records in java . i.e id1,id2. But am getting empty rows.

Below ways only working

```
SELECT *
FROM `js_skills_achievements`
WHERE `skill1`  LIKE '%java%'
   OR `skill2`  LIKE '%java%'
   OR `skill3`  LIKE '%java%'
   OR `skill4`  LIKE '%java%'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I need based on string specified keyword search . can you any one please help on this . Am very appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Consider setting those as FULL TEXT fields and use that for better search mechanism.

Comment: Victim of a poor table design. Don't have several skill columns, have a separate table with several skill rows instead.

Comment: Table designed previous employee , but i need work on this . Can you please is there any way to get results though one string like below.  "java developer in hyderabad"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add full text in your filed

```
ALTER TABLE `js_skills_achievements` ADD FULLTEXT(`skill1`);
ALTER TABLE `js_skills_achievements` ADD FULLTEXT(`skill2`);
ALTER TABLE `js_skills_achievements` ADD FULLTEXT(`skill3`);
ALTER TABLE `js_skills_achievements` ADD FULLTEXT(`skill4`);
```

And then run this query

```
SELECT * FROM js_skills_achievements
WHERE MATCH(skill1,skill2,skill3,skill4) AGAINST ('java developer in nersupalli');
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Subhankar Mitra , its working ,my doubt is if i add FULLTEXT is there any problem in database after long time ??

Comment: No, Full text won't be getting any problem. Just read this you can understand. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `js_skills_achievements`
WHERE `skill1` IN( 'java','php')
   OR `skill2`  IN( 'java','php')
   OR `skill3`  IN( 'java','php')
   OR `skill4`  IN( 'java','php')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10 ;     THIS IS NOT WORKING , CAN U TELL ME PLEASE LIKE YOUR QUERY

Comment: i have multiple skills query is not working for multiple skills , please check ...SELECT * FROM `js_skills_achievements` WHERE MATCH(js_skills_achievements.skill1,js_skills_achievements.skill2,js_skills_achievements.skill3,js_skills_achievements.skill4) AGAINST ('java','php')

Comment: select * from table1 where 
(MATCH (col1,col2) against("java") OR 
(MATCH (col1,col2) against("php") OR 
(MATCH (col1,col2) against("html"))

Comment: SELECT * FROM `js_skills_achievements` WHERE
MATCH (js_skills_achievements.skill1,js_skills_achievements.skill2,js_skills_achievements.skill3,js_skills_achievements.skill4) AGAINST('java') OR (MATCH (js_skills_achievements.skill1,js_skills_achievements.skill2,js_skills_achievements.skill3,js_skills_achievements.skill4) AGAINST('php')

Comment: It Is Not Working ,Getting Error

Comment: Can you send the export script of your table? Then I will check it and send you the exact query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159216/discussion-between-niranjan-and-subhankar-mitra).

Answer (score 2):

A bit ugly way to do this is reverse your like clauses and match your string against columns

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  js_skills_achievements 
WHERE 'java developer in nersupalli' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill1,'%')
  OR 'java developer in nersupalli' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill2,'%')
  OR 'java developer in nersupalli' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill3,'%')
  OR 'java developer in nersupalli' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill4,'%')
  OR skill1  LIKE '%java developer in nersupalli%'
  OR skill2  LIKE '%java developer in nersupalli%'
  OR skill3  LIKE '%java developer in nersupalli%'
  OR skill4  LIKE '%java developer in nersupalli%'
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3cc8a/6)

Comment: Thanks you @M Khalid Junaid  , its working this query

Comment: Hello, i have multiple values in Like condition ,How to write the query ??Please tell me ,Thanks

Comment: @Niranjan its better if you ask a new question

Comment: its not new Question , here you given query for single value search , i have multiple values search like below example . WHERE 'java developer in nersupalli','php developer in nersupalli' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill1,'%')

Comment: @Niranjan I assume you are using full text search right ? so why not use the same, However if you still want to use this approach just repeat where clause part and put  your another value

Comment: Can you please give me the query , am getting error so that can u please tell me exact query

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the search string on a space

```
$words = explode ( ' ' , $string);
```

Than search all the words in skill1. All the words in skill2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are more technical and probably more optimized, however if you wish to have full control on your query, like changing OR to AND and things like this, you can split your query in words and build it manually:

```
//your search query
$query = 'java developer in nersupalli';

//in case you want to add more skills later
$skills = ['skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3', 'skill4'];

//split your query in an array of words
$words = explode(' ', $query);

//build the sql
$condOuter = '';
foreach($skills as $skill){
    $condInner = '';
    foreach($words as $word){
        $condInner .= " OR `$skill` LIKE '%$word%'";
    }
    $condInner = substr($condInner, 4);
    $condOuter .= " OR ($condInner)";
}
$condOuter = substr($condOuter, 4);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `js_skills_achievements` WHERE ' . $condOuter . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `js_skills_achievements`
WHERE '%java developer in nersupalli%' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill1,'%')
   OR '%java developer in nersupalli%' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill2,'%')
   OR '%java developer in nersupalli%' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill3,'%')
   OR '%java developer in nersupalli%' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill4,'%')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `js_skills_achievements`
WHERE '%java developer in nersupalli, php developer%' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill1,'%')
   OR '%java developer in nersupalli,php developer%' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill2,'%')
   OR '%java developer in nersupalli,php developer%' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill3,'%')
   OR '%java developer in nersupalli,php developer%' LIKE CONCAT('%',skill4,'%')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;    THIS IS NOT WORKING CAN U PLEASE TELL ME FOR MULTIPLE SKILLS

Comment: what kind of result you want @Niranjan?

Comment: I tried the above query and got the output..@Niranjan

Comment: Hi.how i write the query for multiple strings ..in WHERE '%java developer in nersupalli%' , I Have  stings like below . WHERE '%java developer in nersupalli%','%php developer%'